# HTTP Redirect in Golang

Tags: go, proxy, httprequest, reverse-proxy

I have this domain http://mynewurl.com/, Which frame forwards to - 
http://oldurl.com:8000 a Go server I’m running for a blog.

I need to have URLs for each post map correctly aka

- http://mynewurl.com/propoal
- http://oldurl.com:8000/proposal

As at the moment visiting links on the main page masks the URL totally so any sharing (hopefully using webmentions) will not reference that post URL but the main URL…

But I was wondering if I can get Golang to play better and listen at the new URL?

```
func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", handlerequest)
  http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

Comment: one suggestion is have index.php which pulls remote page data in and injects it into actual page locate at newurl.com

Comment: aka - CURL PHP https://github.com/joshdick/miniproxy

Answer (score 2):

Look at `httputil.ReverseProxy`

I used it to implement request dumper that essentially does what you described - listen on specific port and forwards to some url.

This is example code. Mileage can vary as I just stripped out parts related to actual work that I am doing in proxy and left pieces that do routing.
But it could be a starting point.

```
func SetProxy(targetUrl string) (newUrl string, err error) {
    var target *url.URL
    target, err = url.Parse(targetUrl)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    origHost := target.Host
    origScheme := target.Scheme
    d := func(req *http.Request) {
        req.URL.Host = origHost
        req.URL.Scheme = origScheme
    }

    p := &httputil.ReverseProxy{Director: d,}
    http.HandleFunc("/", p)

    target.Host = "localhost:8000"
    target.Scheme = "http"
    newUrl = target.String()
    go func() {
        err = http.ListenAndServe(":"+localPort, nil)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    return newUrl, nil
}
```

Comment: thanks, I think based on my use case this is going to be more complicated than I expected